# requestLayout() has no effect when called from onSizeChanged()?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view that display texts and images in columns, in a horizontally scrolling window. It reflows and thus (at least potentially) resizes itself as its content changes; it also reflows and resizes (maintaining a roughly constant area) when the soft keyboard comes and goes and the view height changes.

What I found was that calling [requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29) works (in the sense that it does trigger a call to my [onMeasure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29) overload) most of the time ... but *not* when called from my [onSizeChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) handler.

I was able to work around this by [post()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)ing a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) that called `requestLayout()` and then `post()`ed another `Runnable` that called my code that needs to run after the `onMeasure()` ... but this seems a bit fragile (I don't want to add a delay, yet I do want to be sure that my second `Runnable` does execute after the async `onMeasure()`) and, perhaps because it makes so many passes through the event loop, the screen flashes too much.

Is there some way - in an `onSizeChanged()` - to force an `onMeasure()` (and, probably, another `onSizeChanged()`) to happen before the next [onDraw()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29)?

Comment: Instead of calling `requestLayout()` a second time (and it doesn't work from `onSizeChanged()` because this callback is part of the layout process) why don't you simply compute the correct size in `onMeasure()`?

Comment: I do, and that works. But when the height changes, I reflow - which changes the width - and thus need to trigger a call to `onMeasure()`.

Comment: Your question actually gave me an answer for a problem I just had, thanks :) Your View.post solution works without any side-effects for me. Thanks!

Comment: And about your problem: Why don't you call the code from your second Runnable from inside the onMeasure method?

Comment: it's not only from onSizeChanged that it doesn't work. I tried calling requestLayout from my setImageDrawable method to cause an onMeasure and it wouldn't work. posting it fixed it though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a call back class, maybe two

```
    interface ImGonnaTellClassBThatClassAdidFinished(){

              void ClassHasFinishedProcessing(String YaySuccess);

              void ClassHasFailedProcessing();    

              void SomethingWackaDoodleHappened(String SomeShyte);       
              }
```

Then Overload the class when you need it to perform functions

```
     public class FunctionA{
              ImGonnaTellClassBThatClassAdidFinished someName = new  ImGonnaTellClassBThatClassAdidFinished(){
              @Override
              void ClassHasFinishedProcessing(String YaySuccess){
              //Well I should Call class B with the info then
              //Heres Sting YaySuccess, Use it in the right way
              }
              void ClassHasFailedProcessing(){ 
              //Well I failed and should let someone know
              }
              void SomethingWackaDoodleHappened(String SomeShyte){
              //Well Something else happened and I have some info on it
              }
         //Dont forget to pass it to the class
         ClassB doWorkMeow = new ClassB();
         doWorkMeow.hereYouGo(someName);
     }
```

Make sure you call back when your finished

```
     class ActivityB(){

     public void hereYouGo(ImGonnaTellClassBThatClassAdidFinished finished){
     String itWorked = new String("Hooray");
     finished.ClassHasFinishedProcessing(itWorked);
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps, Good Luck in your endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

The view implementation has a **onlayout** callback method that allows you to modify the child views and the positioning of the view inside the parent layout..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by postponing the call like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    post(() -> someMethod());
}
```