# How to properly add child views to view group?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I recently had to make a custom view that would show a series of ImageView's in a LinearLayout - horizontal fixed height, matching parent width linear layout with fixed size images.  I implemented the following:

```
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);
    removeAllViews();

    for (int i = 0; i < imagesCount; i++) {
        ImageView image = createImageView();
        addView(image);
    }
}
```

However, when LinearLayout becomes visible child views are not visible and onMeasure was not called for any of them. If I background and reopen the app - the views are shown properly and onMeasure is called for every child.

requestLayout() does not work if called from onSizeChanged, so I had to add the following hack in the end of onSizeChanged:

```
post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        requestLayout();
    }
});
```

(via [requestLayout() has no effect when called from onSizeChanged()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345287/requestlayout-has-no-effect-when-called-from-onsizechanged))

Questions:

- Is onSizeChanged() a proper place to addViews()? What is a better place otherwise?
- Is there any better way to force parent view to measure its children after onSizeChanged without using post()?

And a bonus question

- What would be the best source to get deep understanding of android view "life cycle", e.g. when and what gets or does not get called?

I used the following links and a bunch of other stackoverflow discussions:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html
https://plus.google.com/+ArpitMathur/posts/cT1EuBbxEgN

Comment: Why don't you use `ListView`?

Comment: @AntonSavin in fact I have a custom animation applied to those ImageViews and ListView won't be good for that.

Comment: Wow, exact same issue, and exact same solution. doing a post and then add the views there. Broke my head for a few hours over it, there doesn't seem to be a way to properly get the views displayed other then this.